# TypeError : unsupported operand type

Tags: python

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems):
    
    if len(problems)>5:
        print("Error: Too many problems.")

    for cc in problems:
        it=cc.split()
        fi=it[0]
        se=it[1]
        th=it[2]
        #print(fi)

    ### 4 digits and cant be more than 4
        if len(fi)>4 or len(th)>4:
            print('Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits.')
        if not fi.isnumeric() or not th.isnumeric():
            print('Error: Numbers must only contain digits.')
        if  se == '+' or se == '-':
            print('Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'.')

#arithmetic_arranger(['1 + 22'])
arithmetic_arranger(['33 2 22','3 4 5','55 - 5'])
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nrky1\Desktop\python new\ass1.py", line 22, in <module>
    arithmetic_arranger(['33 2 22','3 4 5','55 - 5'])
  File "C:\Users\nrky1\Desktop\python new\ass1.py", line 19, in arithmetic_arranger
    print('Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'.')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Question: Why do I get this error when the elements in the list are strings?
When I print(se) the result is : '2', '4', '-'
How should I correct the code?

Comment: Fix your quoting. You have to escape embedded quotes if they're the same as the quotes that surround the string.

Comment: Or you can just change the surrounding quotes from `'` to `""`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape quotes inside of strings. Otherwise, python won't know the string is continuing. As soon as the first inner quotation mark comes python will assume that the string has ended and then you most likely get a syntax error.

So inside of a string declared with double quotes, like `"This " is a quotation mark."`, you need to escape the inner quotation mark like this `"This \" is a quotation mark."`. The same applies for single quotes like in your code:

```
print('Error: Operator must be \'+\' or \'-\'.')
```

Alternatively, you could declare the string with other outer quotes:

```
print("Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'.")
```